# Use numpy.load on file within zipfile

Tags: python, numpy, python-zipfile

I have a zipfile which contains many npy files (`file1.npy`, `file2.npy`, `file3.npy`, ...). I would like to load them individually without extracting the zipfile on a filesystem. I have tried many things but I can't figure it out.

My guess was:

```
import zipfile
import numpy as np

a = {}

with zipfile.ZipFile('myfiles.zip') as zipper:
    for p in zipper.namelist():
        with zipper.read(p) as f:
            a[p] = np.load(f)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your error? Why isn't it working

Comment: Instead of having a zip of many `*.npy`, you could use [savez_compressed](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html) to save them all into a single `*.npz` which then you don't need to manually unzip it.

Comment: @kennytm I don't have access to the way the files are saved

Comment: I wonder if renaming the file to `*.npz` would fool `np.load` into treating it as a `savez` produced archive.  Or use `np.lib.npyio.NpzFile` directly.

Comment: @hpaulj What I don't understand in your wondering is that I have a zipfile that already contains many npy files... So how can I try your idea ? Can you write an full answer ?

Comment: I just tested `load` on an `zip` archive - it works even if I didn't use `np.savez`.

Comment: For those interested a nice read on the [npy format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html). Particularly: "For a simple way to combine multiple arrays into a single file, one can use ZipFile to contain multiple ”.npy” files. We recommend using the file extension ”.npz” for these archives."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save 2 arrays, each to their own file:

```
In [452]: np.save('x.npy',x)
In [453]: np.save('y.npy',y)
```

With a file browser tool, create a `zip` file, and try to load it:

```
In [454]: np.load('xy.zip')
Out[454]: <numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile at 0xb48968ec>
```

Looks like `np.load` detected the `zip` nature (independent of the name), and returned a `NpzFile` object.  Let's assign it to a variable, and try the normal `.npz` extract:

```
In [455]: xy=np.load('xy.zip')

In [456]: xy['x']
Out[456]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

In [457]: xy['y']
Out[457]: 
array([[ 0,  4,  8],
       [ 1,  5,  9],
       [ 2,  6, 10],
       [ 3,  7, 11]])
```

So `load` can perform the `lazy` load on any `zip` file of `npy` files, regardless of how it's created.

Comment: Very nice answer !

Comment: For those interested a nice read on the [npy format](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html). Particularly: "For a simple way to combine multiple arrays into a single file, one can use ZipFile to contain multiple ”.npy” files. We recommend using the file extension ”.npz” for these archives."

Answer (score 1):

Does the numpy function expect a file object, not the resulting text. For zip files, I generally do something like:

```
with ZipFile(path, mode='r') as archive:
    with io.BufferedReader(archive.open(filename, mode='r')) as file:
```

I am guessing you should pass zipper.open(p, mode='r') into np.load(f). Also, I strong urge you not to do zipper.read(p) since it will read the whole file in memory at once. So, using your code conventions, try:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('myfiles.zip') as zipper:
    for p in zipper.namelist():
        with io.BufferedReader(zipper.open(p, mode='r')) as f:
            a[p] = np.load(f)
```

Comment: the `zipper.open(p,mode='r')` command gives me the following error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 379, in load
    fid.seek(-N, 1) # back-up
io.UnsupportedOperation: seek

Comment: I edit your answer so now the both examples are working

Answer (score 0):

I replace load with BytesIO. I do not know if it is efficient, but works and is more readable :)

```
with ZipFile(fname) as z:
    for p in zipper.namelist():
        tmp =  np.load(io.BytesIO(z.read(p)))
```